# get access data range in c# using oledb

Tags: c#, sql

I've been trying for a couple of days to make a query in c # to a database in access. the thing is that it does not work properly and I am not able to return the data within a range of dates.
I have two tables and I need to send the data to a datagrid, those that are common to both and those that are different in each table, within a range of dates.

This is the query:

```
String query2 = " SELECT [MASTER DATA].[Employee No],[MASTER DATA].[Firstname],[MASTER DATA].[Lastname],Format([MASTER DATA].[ST Date],'dd/mm/yyyy') AS [Illness Date]," +
                " 'BOTH' AS [Report] FROM [MASTER DATA]" +
                " INNER JOIN " +
                " RegistroEnfermedad ON ([MASTER DATA].[ST Date] BETWEEN DateValue('" + f1 + "') AND DateValue('" + f2 + "') AND RegistroEnfermedad.FechaDeBaja BETWEEN DateValue('" + f1 + "') AND DateValue('" + f2 + "')) AND [MASTER DATA].[Employee No] = RegistroEnfermedad.IdEmpleado AND " +
                " [MASTER DATA].[ST Date] = RegistroEnfermedad.FechaDeBaja" +
                " UNION" +
                " SELECT [MASTER DATA].[Employee No],[MASTER DATA].[Firstname],[MASTER DATA].[Lastname],[MASTER DATA].[ST Date], 'ILLNESS REPORT' AS [Report]" +
                " FROM [MASTER DATA]" +
                " WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT RegistroEnfermedad.IdEmpleado, RegistroEnfermedad.FechaDeBaja, RegistroEnfermedad.FechaDeAlta, RegistroEnfermedad.Tipo FROM RegistroEnfermedad WHERE" +
                " [MASTER DATA].[Employee No] = RegistroEnfermedad.IdEmpleado AND" +
                " [MASTER DATA].[ST Date] = RegistroEnfermedad.FechaDeBaja)" +
                " UNION " +
                " SELECT RegistroEnfermedad.IdEmpleado, [MASTER DATA].[Firstname],[MASTER DATA].[Lastname], RegistroEnfermedad.FechaDeBaja,'MY REPORT' AS[Report]" +
                " FROM RegistroEnfermedad,[MASTER DATA] WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT[MASTER DATA].[Employee No], [MASTER DATA].[Firstname],[MASTER DATA].[Lastname]," +
                " [MASTER DATA].[ST Date] FROM [MASTER DATA] WHERE [MASTER DATA].[Employee No] = RegistroEnfermedad.IdEmpleado AND " +
                " [MASTER DATA].[ST Date] = RegistroEnfermedad.FechaDeBaja) order by [MASTER DATA].[Employee No]";
```

The first part works perfect but after the UNION it shows me all the records and looks like is not getting the date range.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I already get the common ones to the two tables, and the non common ones in each table within a range of dates.

```
String query2 = " SELECT [MASTER DATA].[Employee No],[MASTER DATA].[Firstname],[MASTER DATA].[Lastname],Format([MASTER DATA].[ST Date],'dd/mm/yyyy') AS [Illness Date]," +
                " 'BOTH' AS [Report] FROM [MASTER DATA]" +
                " INNER JOIN " +
                " RegistroEnfermedad ON ([MASTER DATA].[ST Date] BETWEEN DateValue('" + f1 + "') AND DateValue('" + f2 + "') AND RegistroEnfermedad.FechaDeBaja BETWEEN DateValue('" + f1 + "') AND DateValue('" + f2 + "')) AND [MASTER DATA].[Employee No] = RegistroEnfermedad.IdEmpleado AND " +
                " [MASTER DATA].[ST Date] = RegistroEnfermedad.FechaDeBaja" +
                " UNION" +
                " SELECT [MASTER DATA].[Employee No],[MASTER DATA].[Firstname],[MASTER DATA].[Lastname],Format([MASTER DATA].[ST Date],'dd/mm/yyyy') AS [Illness Date]," +
                " 'ILLNESS REPORT' AS [Report] FROM [MASTER DATA]" +
                " LEFT JOIN " +
                " RegistroEnfermedad ON ([MASTER DATA].[ST Date] BETWEEN DateValue('" + f1 + "') AND DateValue('" + f2 + "') AND RegistroEnfermedad.FechaDeBaja BETWEEN DateValue('" + f1 + "') AND DateValue('" + f2 + "')) AND [MASTER DATA].[Employee No] = RegistroEnfermedad.IdEmpleado AND " +
                " [MASTER DATA].[ST Date] = RegistroEnfermedad.FechaDeBaja" +
                " WHERE RegistroEnfermedad.FechaDeBaja IS NULL" +
                " UNION" +
                " SELECT RegistroEnfermedad.IdEmpleado,[MASTER DATA].[Firstname],[MASTER DATA].[Lastname],Format(RegistroEnfermedad.FechaDeBaja,'dd/mm/yyyy') AS [Illness Date]," +
                " 'MY REPORT' AS [Report] FROM RegistroEnfermedad" +
                " LEFT JOIN " +
                " [MASTER DATA] ON ([MASTER DATA].[ST Date] BETWEEN DateValue('" + f1 + "') AND DateValue('" + f2 + "') AND RegistroEnfermedad.FechaDeBaja BETWEEN DateValue('" + f1 + "') AND DateValue('" + f2 + "')) AND [MASTER DATA].[Employee No] = RegistroEnfermedad.IdEmpleado AND " +
                " [MASTER DATA].[ST Date] = RegistroEnfermedad.FechaDeBaja" +
                " WHERE [MASTER DATA].[ST Date] IS NULL" +
                " ORDER BY[MASTER DATA].[Employee No] DESC";
```